# label and input in same line on form-group

Tags: css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a form group with both a label and input

```
<div class="col-md-12 form-group">
     <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"  for="name">Name</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" [(ngModel)]="person.name" disabled/>
</div>
```

However the label displays above the input field, i need it at its side. I have bootstrap 4.0 installed.

I've tried with class="col-sm-2 col-form-label" and does not work either.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `col-sm-2` shouldn't be nested directly in `col-md-12`. Use the grid like this...

https://www.codeply.com/go/Gdt1BZs9Hg

```
<form class="col-12">
  <div class="form-row">
     <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"  for="name">Name</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control col-sm-10" name="name" id="name" [(ngModel)]="person.name" disabled/>
  </div>
</form>
```

Notice that `form-row` must used to contain the `col-`. The `col-sm-10` controls the width of the input, so you can change that as needed. Read more in the docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#form-grid

Also, note the **correct use of the grid row > columns** from the Bootstrap docs...

> In a grid layout, content must be placed within columns and only
>   columns may be immediate children of rows... You may also swap .row for .form-row, a variation of our standard grid row that overrides the default column gutters for tighter and more compact layouts.

Answer (score 13):

You can achieve it by using class `form-inline`

```
<div class="form-inline">
    <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
         <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"  for="name">Name</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" [(ngModel)]="person.name" disabled/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10):

The suggestions in other posts didn't work in **Bootstrap 5**. So I tested it by updating one of the [demos](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/input-group/#button-addons) in the Bootstrap 5 documentation and it worked. With this demo application, `<label>`, `<input>` and `<button>` elements can be defined in a single line:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<form role="form">
  <div class="input-group flex-nowrap">
    <span class="input-group-text" id="addon-wrapping">Article Title</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter the new article name..." aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="addon-wrapping">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="article-update-button">Update</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

The form screenshot is available below: For more information, visit the [Bootstrap 5 Input Group](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/overview/) page.

[image: Application Test Image]

Answer (score 4):

See [Bootstrap 4 documentation about Forms](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#inline-forms) and use `form-inline`

```
<div class="col-md-12 form-group form-inline">
     <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"  for="name">Name</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" [(ngModel)]="person.name" disabled/>
</div>
```